# Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file '../../fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-sass

Tonight I got a strange new error when trying to push to Heroku. Normally pushing to Heroku works fine, but for some reason tonight apparently a glyphicon is missing from bootstrap-sass project and Heroku thus fails to accept a push. Here's the error Heroku gives upon `git push heroku master`:

```
Running: rake assets:precompile
   I, [2014-06-17T02:59:50.058577 #768]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_f0c4c8f6-f9ab-40b7-9346-9eb892ea1990/public/assets/karen-1-1a16815583cabbc3e2b1afa7877ecb2f.png
   I, [2014-06-17T02:59:50.063553 #768]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_f0c4c8f6-f9ab-40b7-9346-9eb892ea1990/public/assets/south-c-1-52ab385056b021aa07ad6ae253eb6054.png
   I, [2014-06-17T02:59:59.186515 #768]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_f0c4c8f6-f9ab-40b7-9346-9eb892ea1990/public/assets/application-91b0b1a3925fb425e8b51c103f7009af.js
   rake aborted!
   Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file '../../fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot'
   (in /tmp/build_f0c4c8f6-f9ab-40b7-9346-9eb892ea1990/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss:1)
```

I have all assets to precompile, in config/application.rb I have `config.serve_static_assets = true`.

In app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss I'm making sure to import bootstrap: `@import "bootstrap";`

My gem file:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', github: 'twbs/bootstrap-sass'
gem 'bootstrap-sass-extras'
```

Is this an issue with the bootstrap-sass gem, as I see someone else recently had the same issue with no solution: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/issues/592

Comment: A temporary solution that at least lets me push to Heroku successfully and have my assets precompiled is to remove `github: 'twbs/bootstrap-sass'` from the Gemfile where bootstrap-sass is imported and just have the line `gem 'bootstrap-sass'`. Hopefully this bug will be fixed soon at the Github project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A temporary solution that at least lets me push to Heroku successfully and have my assets precompiled is to remove `github: 'twbs/bootstrap-sass'` from the `Gemfile` where `bootstrap-sass` is imported and just have the `line gem 'bootstrap-sass'`. Hopefully this bug will be fixed soon at the Github project.

*Edit 5 months later*: this bug was fixed a few nights after this question was asked.